# Finding all small monoids with the help of GAP

Tags: monoid, gap, computer-algebra-systems

In GAP there is the command [`AllSmallGroups(n)`](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/pkg/SmallGrp/doc/chap1.html#X7BB133CB7AA8F465) to construct all finite groups of order $n$ up to isomorphism.

> Question: Is there a similar method (or package) in GAP that produces all finite monoids (or even semigroups) of order $n$ up to isomorphism?

This is probably a much harder problem than for groups but already a program which works till $n=10$ might be helpful.

Comment: helpful for what ??

Comment: @J.-E. Testing some things and searching for certain monoids with specific properties for example.

Comment: Strictly speaking, `AllSmallGroups` does not _construct_ groups - it retrieves them from the data library. The function that re-runs the construction is `ConstructAllGroups` from the GrpConst package. While there is no package to _construct_ all semigroups or monoids (see https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.6023 for the approach used), the results of constructing them are put into a data library and are available in the GAP package Smallsemi - see my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Smallsemi package (https://gap-packages.github.io/smallsemi/), as its description says, "is a data library of semigroups of small size. It provides all semigroups with at most 8 elements as well as various information about these objects". For example:

```
gap> LoadPackage("smallsemi");
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Smallsemi -   A library of small semigroups
by Andreas Distler & James Mitchell
For contents, type: ?Smallsemi:
Loading Smallsemi 0.6.12 ...
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
true
gap> NrSmallSemigroups(6);
15973
gap> NrSmallSemigroups(3);
18
gap> AllSmallSemigroups(3,IsMonoidAsSemigroup,true);
#I  Smallsemi: loading data for semigroup properties. Please be patient.
[ <small semigroup of size 3>, <small semigroup of size 3>, 
  <small semigroup of size 3>, <small semigroup of size 3>, 
  <small semigroup of size 3>, <small semigroup of size 3> ]
```

Please see the documentation at https://gap-packages.github.io/smallsemi/doc/chap0.html. In particular, note functions like `EnumeratorOfSmallSemigroups` and `IteratorOfSmallSemigroups` which should help to deal with large collections of semigroups.

**Remark:** The number of semigroups and monoids of small orders is given in OEIS [A001423](https://oeis.org/A001423) and [A058133](https://oeis.org/A058133) respectively.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

I have not seen such a construction package, and I think it is unlikely that such a package exists:

From experience in constructing groups (or combinatorial structures) the enumeration process relies on two parts:
An extension process of smaller objects (cohomology in the case of groups), as well as an effective isomorphism test.

I have seen neither for monoids (though one could try to implement brute-force versions) -- indeed https://mathoverflow.net/questions/308245/how-to-show-two-semigroups-are-isomorphic indicates that the isomorphism test for semigroups would be harder than one for groups.